# Windows 10 wifi icon missing, can't pick up signals, limited connections in Firefox

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, icons, signal

Windows 10 did an update that made my laptop fans/hard drive go crazy and crashed my system. Since that "update" and restarting my wifi icon from the taskbar/notification area is missing. I've followed the steps to get it back I came across on other sites, but no luck. In the notification settings, the network on/off switch is grayed out. I've refreshed the Explorer process, did the quick actions steps, and tried the notification settings, but as I said above, the network option isn't available.

Today they shut off my service, turned it back on, and I'm having more problems. Tgoing a roundabout way I discovered that my laptop isn't picking up any wifi signals! And any other browser besides Firefox won't connect. Even Firefox is running into some trouble.

I'm SOMEHOW somewhat connected, but to which Wifi I have no idea. I can't even find that out. My phone is connected to my home wifi and is working fine. The phones work. Even the AT&T wifi status page seems okay. But I can't troubleshoot because Windows says it needs a connection to do that. I'd really appreciate any help. I running Windows 10. If you need any more info from me let me know. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Use the manufacturer's driver update app and update all drivers including BIOS.  Restart and run a Windows 10 Repair install from the Media Creation Link:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10   Use the second link on the MCL page to repair in place.

Comment: Thank you! Oh God no. I'm not computer illiterate, but I don't think I could update the BIOS... and I've already had to do so many repair installs... It turns out I got the internet up and running and it's connected to my network. I can see the info through the control panel or task manager. But the icon is still missing, wifi options don't show up in settings, and it won't try to pick up nearby networks. Is there anything else I can do? Thank you so much for your reply though!

Comment: If you have done a Repair Install in this case and still no Wireless, and you are sure the wireless card is good ((No issues in Device Manager), then you may need to (a) try a new Wireless Card and/or (b) do a fresh install

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I meant in the past I've had to do that. But I updated the wireless adapter and restarted my router and the internet is stable, except for the issues above (no icons, not picking up connections, ect.).

Comment: In addition to the above, get the Driver Update App for your computer and see if you can update BIOS, Chipset, Video and any other drivers you can. That is all that is left in addition to the other suggestions.

Comment: Do you have specific driver update app in mind? Thank you again!

Comment: Your machine manufacturer should have an update app - at the very least a support site with drivers. I always try to use the manufacturer’s drivers

Comment: Unfortunately, my laptop's manufacturer's page for my model doesn't have the most recent drivers nor does it have an update app. I either have to use the device manager or google search for the drivers. I think I might have a less popular brand of a laptop (it's a Sager). Well, I did save money up to finally get a new laptop, one that actually works well. I guess it's time to start shopping... But if you do have an updater app in mind (hopefully a free one) could you share it with me? I'm searching for some, but I wanted to hear your opinion. Thank you again!

Comment: There are several. Some are paid.  Not to many are free. Here is one that has a free version: https://bdu.bitdriverupdater.com/

Comment: I'll check it out! Thank you so, so much for all your help<3